# How to break during reduce method?

Tags: javascript, express, promise, reduce

```
data_set.reduce(function(prev,curr,index,arr){                        
    return prev.then(function(){
        db.health_consideration.findAll({
            where:{ FoodId :  curr.id }
        }).then(function(ing_sets){
            sumData[2].push(ing_sets);

            if(index == arr.length-3){
              //I want to break this point. 
            }

            if(index == arr.length-1){
                console.log('wow3');
                console.log(sumData[2].length);
                data_set.reduce(function(prev,curr,index,arr){

                    return prev.then(function(){
                        db.guaranteed_analysis.findAll({
                            where:{ FoodId :  curr.id }
                        }).then(function(ing_sets){
                            sumData[3].push(ing_sets);
                            if(index == arr.length-1){
                                console.log('wow4');
                                console.log(sumData[3].length);
                            }

                        })
                        .catch(function(e){
                            console.log(e);
                        });
                    })
                },Promise.resolve())
                .catch(function(e){
                    console.log(e);
                })    
            }

        })
        .catch(function(e){
            console.log(e);
        });
    })
},Promise.resolve())
.catch(function(e){
    console.log(e);
})
```

I want to make it like  (db.health_consideration find all data using multiple food id) -> (db.guaranteed_analysis find all data using multiple food id).

but if error occurs during finding data. I want to stop next step.

ex)

```
if(index == arr.length-3){
              //I want to break this point. 
            }
```

Comment: You could `slice` the array before `reduce`-ing. (`arr.slice(0, arr.length - 3).reduce()`)

Comment: Typically, you dont interrupt a reduction once it's started. Clojure's the only language I know that allows early exits.

Comment: ```.reduce``` is done synchronously.  If you're looking to use ```.reduce``` in asynchronous manners, you may want to check out RxJS.